# Calculate mean and standard deviation for a column

Tags: bash, awk

```
i    z    r                    

1   -30   3.5                 
2   -30   3.4                 
3   -30   3.6                  
...                             
10  -30   4.2                  
1   -29.5 4.6                 
2   -29.5 2.8                  
3   -29.5 3.4                    
....
10  -29.5 3.6
1   -29.0 2.5
2   -29.0 2.6
3   -29.0 3.0
```

I have a file that contents 3 column (above) . except the first line (i z r), my data file has 600 rows. First I thought about using a command to split the 3rd column into 10-lines-continuos sections, and then use another script to calculate the means and SD for each section ("i" from 1 to 10). After that, I want to put all results into a file (result.dat).The result file will content 3 column like below:
   z  means  SD
I tried the scripts below. However I don't know how to combine them in 1 script file.

```
10 = split($3, array, " ")

BEGIN {n=0 ; s=0; ss =0}
NF=10 {n++; s+= $3; ss == $3;}
END {
means=(s)/10
SD=sqrt((ss-m)*(ss-m))/10 
prin $2 $means $SD}' data.dat >> result.dat
```

Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hint: `$1==1{i=0}{a[i]=$2;b[i++]=$3;}$1==10{/*calculate mean/SD based on a[0]...a[9]*/}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
    { s += $3; ss += $3*$3;
      if ($1 == 10)
      { print $2, s/10, sqrt((ss-s*s/10)/10) >"result.dat"; s = ss = 0 }
    }
```